# how to insert data from one table to another in mysql

Tags: mysql

i have two tables in my database named

```
newpc(Total_PC,IP,MAC,Lab_Code,PC_Name,Purchase_Order_No,Brand,Model_Name,Prise,Processor,Ram,HDD,HDD_Type)
```

and

```
 deadstock(MAC,Lab,MAC,Lab_Code,PC_Name,Purchase_Order_No,Brand,Model_Name,Prise,Processor,Ram,HDD,HDD_Type)
```

and i want to add data from newlab to deadstock 
my code is

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `deadstock` (`MAC`,`Lab_Code`,`PC_Name`,`Purchase_Order_No`,`Brand,Model`,`Price`,`Processor`,`Ram`,`HDD`,`HDD_Type`)VALUES(
          SELECT (MAC,'Lab_Code','PC_Name',Purchase_Order_No,'Brand','Model_Name',Price,'Processor',Ram,HDD,'HDD_Type'))
          FROM newlab WHERE PC_Name='.$PC_Name.'";
```

but it doesnt work.  Query is not performing any insert operation in deadstock table

Comment: Are you getting any errors?  Is there any output from your query "SELECT (MAC,'Lab_Code','PC_Name',Purchase_Order_No,'Brand','Model_Name',Price,'Processor',Ram,HDD,'HDD_Type'))
          FROM newlab WHERE PC_Name='.$PC_Name.'"

Comment: yes it does gives an error message like "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '&quot;INSERT INTO `deadstock` (`MAC`,`Lab_Code`,`PC_Name`,`Purchase_Order_No`,`Brand,' at line 1"

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `deadstock` (`MAC`,`Lab_Code`,`PC_Name`,`Purchase_Order_No`,`Brand,Model`,`Price`,`Processor`,`Ram`,`HDD`,`HDD_Type`)
          SELECT MAC,'Lab_Code','PC_Name',Purchase_Order_No,'Brand','Model_Name',Price,'Processor',Ram,HDD,'HDD_Type'
          FROM newlab WHERE PC_Name='.$PC_Name.'";
```

No `VALUES` and Brackets - ()!

Comment: it gives an error message like #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '&quot;INSERT INTO `deadstock` (`MAC`,`Lab_Code`,`PC_Name`,`Purchase_Order_No`,`Brand,' at line 1

Comment: what does the select statement return?